# Why does my result contain true when using regex's -match?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, find

I'm simply trying to write a function that takes a string and isolates a substring and returns it. That value will then be copied to a csv file.

My function looks like this:

```
Function FileName ($msg)
{
$msg -match ', (.*) owned'
$result=$matches[1]
return $result
}
```

For example, I want the result to contain "New Text Document.txt - Notepad", I call:

```
FileName "Document 3, New Text Document.txt - Notepad owned by SYSTEM on \\COMPUTERNAME was printed on {736660DE-4F30-4949-A1B1-68701735DAA8} through port {736660DE-4F30-4949-A1B1-68701735DAA8}.  Size in bytes: 127183. Pages printed: 1. No user action is required."
```

but when I export it to the csv file, it appears as "True New Text Document.txt - Notepad".
How do I remove the "True"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-match` is a Boolean operator that returns $true or $false depending on whether or not it found a match.  If you don't capture the result of executing the operator in a variable or redirect it, it will be part of the function's output. Typically you would use it like so:

```
function FileName ($msg)
{
    if ($msg -match ', (.*) owned')
    {
        $matches[1]
    }
    else { .. figure out what to do here .. }
}
```